# Socket.io transport types

Tags: node.js, sockets

I have been searching a lot for a while about various transport types of socket.io. I found below list of transport types:

1. websocket
2. flashsocket
3. htmlfile
4. xhr-polling
5. jsonp-polling
6. polling

Not sure if the list is in the order of priority. But, its very strange that there is no documentation to describe all these transport types in a bit detail. Such as how are the connections being handled and served in each of the cases.

This is important to understand from performance point of view. Like if my node.js app has more polling connections than websocket connections then, does it hamper something so that i can configure socket.io to accept only wesocket transport types or something sort of. For this I want to understand what happens in each of these transport types.

Please share something, am stuck from quite some time with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 1.3.6, the supported transports are:

- polling-jsonp
- polling-xhr
- polling
- websocket

Websocket is the priority, and the other methods are all based on polling and are quite similar.

You can look at the transports implementation [here](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io/tree/master/lib/transports).